Convolution integral with a dirac delta function as it pertains to obtaining the Heaviside step function
I have the following convolution integral:
$$\tag{1}I = \int_0^r r^3\delta(R-r)dr$$ This question could also be "how to obtain the indefinite integral of (1)?" which we'll see why a bit further down.
Briefly explaining the setup, $R$ is a constant $R>0$ and lies somewhere in the domain of r: $0\le r <\infty$. For physical reasons, we want to keep our bounds of integration within the domain $0\le r \le R$ where we note that $r$ can be $R$, otherwise our delta function would be $0$ everywhere.
I am not entirely certain of this, but I'm expecting the result to be
$$\tag{2} \boxed{I = R^3\Big(\Theta(R-r)-1\Big)}$$
Just a quick peek over on Wolframalpha which ties back to a potential alternative to the problem statement, the indefinite integral should be $R^3\Theta(R-r)+C$ which if I were to set $C=0$ and plug in for our bounds of integration $R^3\Theta(R-r)|_0^r$ (understanding that $\Theta(R) = 1$) we would get our expected result (2).

Attempting integration by parts:
$$\tag{3}\matrix{u = r^3 & dv=\delta(R-r) \\ du = 3r^2dr & v = \Theta(R-r)} \\ r^3\Theta(R-r)|_0^r-3\int_0^r r^2 \theta(R-r)dr$$
$$\tag{4}\matrix{u = r^2 & dv=\Theta(R-r) \\ du = 2r dr & v =\int\cases{1 & $r\le R$\\ 0 } dr =\cases{r & $r \le R$\\ R}} \\ R^3-2\int_0^R r^2 dr = \frac{R^3}{3}$$
$$\tag{5}I=r^3\Theta(R-r) - 3\Big(\frac{R^3}{3}\Big) = r^3\Theta(R-r)-R^3$$
I'm guessing that in (3), $u$ would be $u = R^3$ but I don't understand why. And yes, in (4) I did change my bound of integration to be over the full domain $0\le r \le R$ that arises in our piecewise definition.

The object $\delta(R-r)$, called the Dirac Delta, is not a function.  Rather, it is a Generalized Function, also known as a  Distribution.
Instead of relying on the theory of distributions, we shall interpret the Dirac Delta as a measure.  Then, we can write the object of interest as the Riemann-Stieltjes integral
$$\begin{align}
-\int_{0}^r r'^3 \,dH(R-r')&=-r^3H(R-r)+\int_0^r 3r^2 H(R-r')\,dr'\\\\
&=-r^3H(R-r)+\begin{cases}r^3&R>r\\\\R^3&R<r\end{cases}\\\\&=\begin{cases}0&,R>r\\\\R^3&,R<r\end{cases}\\\\
&=R^3H(r-R)
\end{align}$$
NOTE:
Inasmuch as $H(r-R)=1-H(R-r)$, we can write
$$-\int_{0}^r r'^3 \,dH(R-r')=R^3\left(1-H(R-r)\right)$$
which is opposite in sign of Equation $(2)$ in the OP.

Thank you! I didn't know that we could change the variable of integration by combining it with the dirac delta (not a function as you bring up). I worked it out and can verify your result.

You're welcome.  My pleasure.  And pleased to hear that you worked it out.
